# Passing parameters to _beginthreadex

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading

I'm attempting to do some basic parallelisation using _beginthreadex, and passing parameters as per an example I was given, but it won't work.

Any ideas?

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <process.h>



void MyThread(void *data)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!"; 
}

int main()
{
    _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MyThread, NULL, 0, NULL); 
    while(true);
}
```

EDIT:

Why won't passing NULL as an argument work? (Since the function takes no arguments anyway?)

Passing NULL as an arguments list worked fine with _beginthread.

Comment: what does it do?  How doesn't it work?

Comment: error C2664: '_beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void (__cdecl *)(void *)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'

Comment: apparently your function needs to return an integer. See my edited post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code has two errors in it, neither of which are related to the parameter to the thread function --- `NULL` is fine for that, as you surmised.

The problems are in the signature of the thread function, and the error you are getting points this out. Firstly, it must be a `__stdcall` function, and secondly it must return an `unsigned int`. Your function is `__cdecl` and returns `void`.

```
unsigned __stdcall MyThread(void *data)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!"; 
    return 0;
}
```

should fix the problem for you.

Answer (score 6):

obviously in your code you are not passing any parameter. To pass a variable you have to do the following (for example):

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <process.h>

void MyThread(void *data)
{
    int x = static_cast<int*>(data);
    std::cout << "Hello World! " << x; 
}

int main()
{
    int x = 10;
    _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MyThread, &x, 0, NULL); 
    while(true);
}
```

UPDATE: Since you posted the compilation problem later:
apparently your thread function needs to return an integer:

```
int MyThread(void *data)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!"; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But no variable needs to be passed since MyThread accepts no arguments?

Comment: A it does have an argument list a void* and B yes because NULL is a valid void * value.

Comment: of course, the code you wrote is acceptable and propably compilable. But I thought you wanted to pass a parameter, or didn't you?

Comment: should int main() be: int* x = new int(10); and _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MyThread, x, 0, NULL);???   with MyThread casting it to an int* pointer?

Comment: Its not necessary to use dynamic allocation in this case, as ``i`` is guaranteed to persist for the duration of the thread.

Answer (score 1):

You pass your data through the fourth parameter.  This passes a pointer to `i`:

```
unsigned __stdcall thread(void *arg)
{
    int *iptr = (int*)arg;
    ...
}

int i;
_beginthreadex(0, 0, thread, &i, 0, 0);
```

Note that the thread function signature I used here is different than what you use: I return an `unsigned` and use the `__stdcall` calling convention -- this is the signature [_beginthreadex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kdzttdcb.aspx) expects.

Depending on what you're trying to do, the new [Concurrency Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504870.aspx) features in VC++ might be simpler to use than explicitly managing your own threads.

**Edit** in response to question edit:

You can pass any valid void pointer, including NULL.  If you do that, you can even leave out the parameter's name since you're not using it:

```
unsigned __stdcall thread(void*)
{
    ...
}

_beginthreadex(0, 0, thread, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: your function does not return any value. this will most certainly lead to a compiler warning/error.

Comment: Yes, I left that out for brevity.  You also of course shouldn't try to call `_beginthreadex` from outside of a function!

Answer (score 0):

`The fourth parameter in _beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MyThread, NULL, 0, NULL) are arguments to the function MyThread`

Right now you are passing NULL to it so `void* data` must be getting a NULL pointer

```
struct X  
{  
    int a;  
    int b;  
};

X* x = (X*)malloc(sizeof(X));  

x->a = 5;  
x->b = 6;  
_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, MyThread, NULL, x, NULL);
```

The above code will pass pointer `x` to the function `MyThread()`.
**Do take care of X, as it better should be allocated by malloc or new. Do not create it on stack until you use a thread join**

Comment: NULL is a valid void* type isn't it?

Comment: @Atomerz: yeah you are right. I misunderstood the question and did not see the EDIT part of the question

Answer (score 0):

The argument to _beginthreadex must be a function with the `__stdcall` calling convention. Your function has `__cdecl`. A simple insertion of `__stdcall` at the correct spot should solve the problem.

```
void __stdcall MyThread(void *data)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!"; 
}
```

Comment: I added that in, but I'm still getting this error - 

error C2664: '_beginthreadex' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'void (__stdcall *)(void *)' to 'unsigned int (__stdcall *)(void *)'