# C++ how can I call a thread with parameters

Tags: c++, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Passing parameters to _beginthreadex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968076/passing-parameters-to-beginthreadex)

How can I call `TestFunction2` instead of `TestFunction1` in `ExecuteLocalThread` using `beginthreadex` as `TestFunction2` contains 3 additional parameters

```
unsigned __stdcall TestFunction1(void* timerPointer)
{
    unsigned result =0;
    printf("thread is running\n");
    return result;
}

unsigned __stdcall TestFunction2(void* timerPointer, wchar_t *appId, wchar_t *userName, wchar_t *password)
{
    unsigned result =0;
    printf("thread is running\n");
    return result;
}

void ExecuteLocalThread()
{
    HANDLE   heartBeatThread;
    unsigned int hbThreadID;
    heartBeatThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0 , &TestFunction1, (void*)this, CREATE_SUSPENDED, &hbThreadID);
    ResumeThread( heartBeatThread );
}
```

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5968076/passing-parameters-to-beginthreadex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a struct which contains all the data you want to pass then pass a pointer to that into your thread entrypoint

```
typedef struct MyThreadData {
    void* timerPointer;
    wchar_t *appId;
    wchar_t *userName;
    wchar_t *password;
}; MyThreadData


unsigned int hbThreadID;
void* threadData = calloc(1, sizeof(*threadData));
/* populate threadData */
heartBeatThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0,
                               &TestFunction1, threadData,
                               CREATE_SUSPENDED, &hbThreadID);


unsigned __stdcall TestFunction1(void* ptr) {
    MyThreadData* threadData = (MyThreadData*)ptr;
    unsigned result;
    printf("thread is running\n");
    result = TestFunction2(ptr->timerPointer, ptr->appId, ptr->userName, ptr->password);
    free(threadData);
    return result;
}

unsigned __stdcall TestFunction2(void* timerPointer, wchar_t *appId, wchar_t *userName, wchar_t *password) {
    unsigned result =0;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks simonc but this is not working.

Comment: These two words ("ptr->" and "&TestFunction2"
) are problematic in following two line of code

result = TestFunction2(ptr->timerPointer, ptr->appId, ptr->userName, ptr->password);

heartBeatThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0,
                               &TestFunction2, (void*)threadData,
                               CREATE_SUSPENDED, &hbThreadID);

Comment: @user1482702 There was an important typo in my suggested code.  Be sure to pass &TestFunction1 into _beginthreadex

Answer (score 8):

Use C++11 threads:

```
std::thread thr(func, arg0, arg1, arg2);
```

Comment: It's the only sensible solution

Answer (score 0):

Creating a struct as suggested works. If the code is inside a class and that class already contains the info, you could use that, too:

```
unsigned __stdcall TestFunctionProxy(void* p)
{
    assert(p);
    MyClass* c = static_cast<MyClass*>(p);
    c->TestFunction();
    return 0;
}
```

If this doesn't work because TestFunction() is private, make it a friend function. BTW: starting a thread in suspended state and then releasing it is unnecessary. Just start the thread directly.

Lastly, just to keep in mind, using a proper C++ threading library like e.g. Boost.Thread would make this more flexible and provide solutions to your question how to pass further parameters.